# PHPUnit Test error: Object of class (...) could not be converted to string

Tags: php, phpunit, vfs

First of all, I'm new in PHPUnit testing and PHP, sorry if I'm missing something too obvious.

Ok, now, for my question: I'm using a Virtual File System called [VfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) to test the function [`unlink( )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php). For some reason in my testing this error occurred:

```
[bianca@cr-22ncg22 tests-phpunit]$ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /var/www/html/tests-phpunit/phpunit.xml

E

Time: 27 ms, Memory: 4.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) test\UnlinkTest\UnlinkTest::testUnlink
Object of class App\Libraries\Unlink could not be converted to string

/var/www/html/tests-phpunit/test/UnlinkTest.php:21
/home/bianca/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:153
/home/bianca/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:105

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I know is something with my Unlink class and what it's returning, but I don't know what is.

The class I'm testing:

```
class Unlink {

    public function unlinkFile($file) {

        if (!unlink($file)) {
            echo ("Error deleting $file");
        }
        else {
            echo ("Deleted $file");
        }

        return unlink($file);
    }

}

?>
```

The class where my tests are:

```
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStream;
use App\Libraries\Unlink;

class UnlinkTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        $root = vfsStream::setup('home');
        $removeFile = new Unlink();
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $root = null;
    }

    public function testUnlink() {
        $root = vfsStream::setup('home');
        $removeFile = new Unlink();
        vfsStream::newFile('test.txt', 0744)->at($root)->setContent("The new contents of the file");
        $this->$removeFile->unlinkFile(vfsStream::url('home/test.txt'));
        $this->assertFalse(var_dump(file_exists(vfsStream::url('home/test.txt'))));
    }

}

?>
```

Anybody can help me to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure about doing `assertFalse(var_dump(...))`  - var_dump doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: I removed the `var_dump`, but the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is because initially you create this local variable:

```
$removeFile = new Unlink();
```

But then you refer to it as `$this->$removeFile` when you do:

```
$this->$removeFile->unlinkFile(vfsStream::url('home/test.txt'));
```

That's not correct; you might use that where you have a class variable and  you want to refer to it dynamically.  e.g.

```
class YourClass {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo = 'hello';
        $this->bar = 'world';
    }

    public function doStuff() {
        $someVariable = 'foo';

        echo $this->$someVariable;  // outputs 'hello'
    }
}
```

All you need to do is get rid of the `$this`, and change it to:

```
$removeFile->unlinkFile(vfsStream::url('home/test.txt'));
```

Comment: I knew it was a simple error like this! haha Thank you, @duncan. Now I need to fix other problems with vfsStream lol

Comment: @B.Pereira if this answer solved your issue please accept it. If you're not familiar with stackoverflow please take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour